# Is emulation mode available in Cloo?

Tags: c#, opencl, cloo

Is there a way of enabling emulation mode in OpenCL trough Cloo? I can't find anything about it on web. Or maybe using CPU as ComputeContext.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by emulation but with a somewhat recent cpu from intel or amd you should be able to install an opencl driver that lets your application find the cpu as a platform.